# Trailforks for road bikes?

Tags: road-bike

Is there an iPhone app like Trailforks but for road bikes? I'd like to see where paved paths (bikes only, no cars) are located.

Comment: For those not in the know, Trailforks is an app that shows where to find mountain bike trails.  Particularly useful when trying to find unofficial trails that do not have way-markers and/or published maps.

Comment: This would be better on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ because its not about bikes, its about software for bikes.

Comment: @Criggie: Uh...no.

Comment: @4thSpace "uh, yes".   You're asking for "software about cycling"  which is very similar to the classic "boat-programming" thread on SE.  Read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/ for more information.   Don't take it personally - Stackexchange is a bit different sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google maps will show you paved trials open to bicycles and roads with dedicated bike lanes.

If you are a Strava user, you can use the route creation tool with heatmap turned on. That highlights bicycle trails very effectively.

Ride with GPS has a bicycle trails overlay in its route planner.

Really, any significant paved bicycle trails in a given location will be easy to find with a simple Google search, for instance searching for ['paved bicycle paths washington dc'](https://www.google.com/search?q=paved%20bicycle%20paths%20washington%20dc) turns up all the major paths in the area.

Comment: I didn't know you could add the heat map to the route finder. Unfortunately, it colours lightly-used roads and trails in light blue -- so they look exactly like rivers. Fail.

Comment: Definitely not looking for bike lanes as mentioned in the OP. I went back to Google Maps. I can see the bike path I'm particularly interested in. It switches from a solid green line (Dedicated lane) to a dashed line (bicycle-friendly roads). This path is not on streets. The problem is that this paved path turns into dirt in some sections but Google Maps does not note that. There's a marker for "Dirt/unpaved trails" but that isn't used in those sections on the path. Instead, I think it is using the bicycle-friendly roads marker. So if "bicycle-friendly roads"=dirt, then that is helpful info.

Comment: @4thSpace Does the trail have it's own web page? Paved bike trails are often state or county parks and appear in state or county park websites. They often provide maps which show the trail surface.

Comment: I haven't found anything like that for this one.